Complexity of LQR without Dynamic Programming
I am trying to understand LQR using this material: https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/dlqr.pdf.
In the material, the LQR problem is seen as a least square problem with a dynamics written with a matrix vector form as
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{0}\\ \vdots \\x_{N}
\end{bmatrix}=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & &\\
B & 0      & \cdots & \\
AB &  B & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \\
A^{N-1}B & A^{N-2}B & \cdots &B 
\end{bmatrix}
}_{M}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{0} \\ \vdots \\
u_{N-1}
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ A \\\vdots\\ A^{N}
\end{bmatrix}
x_{0},
\end{equation}
where $A,B$ are Jacobian of the dynamics, state $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and control $u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. The material says that solving the problem naively requires $\mathcal{O}(N^{3}nm^{2})$. I believe this is because of the factorization of related to the big matrix
$M\in\mathbb{R}^{Nn \times (N-1)m} $ showing up in the dynamics. I understand up to this part. However, it also says on page 13 the following.

gives an efficient, recursive method to solve LQR least-squares problem;
cost is
$\mathcal{O}(Nn^{3})$
(but in fact, a less naive approach to solve the LQR least-squares
problem will have the same complexity)

I believe that 1 refers to Dynamic Programming(DP) technique, but I cannot understand 2. Does this mean that there exist an approach other than DP that can solve the LQR problem in $\mathcal{O}(Nn^{3})$? If so, would you give me a reference?
